# url rewriting is not working using htaccess in windows XAMP

Tags: php, .htaccess

The .htaccess code is given below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shoppe
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^cat/([^/]+)$ sub-category.php?category=$1 [NC,L]re
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you enable the rewrite module on httpd.conf?

Comment: where can i enable that??

Comment: Go to XAMPP control panel click config on apache then click httpd.conf find this on your text editor : 

#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

and remove the '#', then restart apache. I hope this solves because I did the same before.

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteRule has bad flag delimiters, it should be something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.php$ /sub-category.php?category=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Also, as Jomar Llevado says, you should make sure mod_rewrite is enabled:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2